# Intellij IDEA 10 hide .aj (aspectj) files

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-roo

I have a ROO project, and I am developing it in Intellij, it would be handy if I could hide all the aspect files (.aj) from the module view tree. Anybody know how? or if it is possible at all?

Comment: Jim's answer will work, however I did notice that the \*\_Roo\_\*.aj files also no longer show up in the VCS changes window, nor in the list of files when committing a change. As long as you realize that fact and use command-line for your VCS operations instead of IntelliJ, then everything should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer (changing configuration in settings) caused all the methods provided by aj can't be detected by Intellij and causing error here and there.
Configuring a new scope seems to be a better answer.

Use "Edit Scopes" in your Project sidebar setting (found in Settings -> Project Settings -> Scopes)
Add a new scope, e.g. "Non-Roo" 
with pattern like "!*_Roo_*"

Then you can switch between the two scopes to show/hide the Roo files.

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> File Types -> Ignore files and folders (at the bottom)

Comment: This will prevent Aspects from Roo ITDs to compile in IDEA

Answer (score 1):

To prevent filtering out non-Roo managed aspects, follow Timofei's navigation instructions

> Settings -> File Types -> Ignore files
>   and folders (at the bottom)

and add  *_Roo_*.aj; to the end of the list.